# TypeError: web3.eth.accounts.create is not a function

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc

the javascript file  used to communicate with test-net :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('Web3 found');
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

$("#creatAccountSubmit").click(function(){
var count = $("#noOfAccount").val();
for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  var accounts = web3.eth.accounts.create();
  console.log(accounts);

}    
});
});
```

I am using ganache-cli as a local provider I don't know which web3 version it uses but the package.json file in my project folder seems to use 1.0.0

```
{
"name": "project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.30"
}
}
```

but after running the web page to create an account am getting an error

> "TypeError: web3.eth.accounts.create is not a function"

but the node consoles (it uses web3-1.0.0) I can run the same command, 
How can I resolve this error, I think changing the web3 version used by ganache-cli will do the task but don't know how to do it?

Comment: Can you try `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()`?

Comment: web3.personal.newAccount(newPassword) Try this too

Comment: Yeah web3.personal.newAccount() worked, arent any good documemtation available for web3 0.20.0. I cany only find for the version 1.0.0 .

Comment: You may refer https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account can be created using the following command.

```
           web3.personal.newAccount(newPassword);
```

This method generates a new private key and stores it in the key store directory. The key file is encrypted with the given passphrase/password and returns the address of the new account.

Reference :-   https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_newaccount